# Win32::OLE Cannot capture VB form elements in excel

Tags: perl, excel, office-automation, win32ole, vba

The excel file I am trying to automate using Win32::OLE has some macros
Question:

1. There is a button at E2, I am trying to get it using
   `my $array = $Sheet->Range("E2:E2")->{'Value'};` , but I get undef. How do I simulate this button click?
2. This click calls a macro "someAction" , if i run this macro like: 
   `$Excel->Run("someAction");` a form opens up, which has 2 text boxes, is there a way to fill in values for those input fields?

Comment: 1) Try "E2" not "E2:E2".   2) One way is to modify the form to load optional values when passed in and then call the macro with the optional values as arguments.